# how to save radio button clicked value in hidden field?

Tags: javascript, jquery, laravel

```
<script>
    $(document).ready(function(){
        var value = $('input[name="yesno"]').change(function(){
            if($('#imageCheck').prop('checked')){
                // alert('Image Option checked!');
            }else if($('#textCheck').prop('checked')){
                // alert('Text Option Checked!');
            }
        });
    });
</script>

<input type="radio" onclick="javascript:imageTextCheck();" name="yesno" 
  id="imageCheck"/>&nbsp&nbsp&nbsp<b>Text</b>
<input type="radio" onclick="javascript:imageTextCheck();"name="yesno" 
  id="textCheck"/>

<input type="hidden" name="radioCheck" id="radioCheck" value=""/>
```

how i can save the value of radio button in hidden field. If i Click on image it saves image value.

Comment: Why? The radio button is an input in its own right. Can't you just use its value when you need it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
    var value = $('input[name="yesno"]').click(function(){
      $('#radioCheck').val($(this).val());
    });
    setInterval(() => console.log( $('#radioCheck').val() ), 1000);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type="radio" name="yesno" value="imageCheck" id="imageCheck"/><label for="imageCheck">imageCheck</label>
<br />
<input type="radio" name="yesno"value="textCheck" id="textCheck"/><label for="textCheck">textCheck</label>
<input type="hidden" name="radioCheck" id="radioCheck" value=""/>
```

hope this one helps you :)

the setInterval is just to print out the hidden field's value each and every second so when you click on a radio button you can see that it sets the hidden input's value

Answer (score 0):

Here is a simple solution for your problem: I have written one sample of code to explain the problem:

**First**: OnClick of radio button save the value of radio button if it is checked.

**var radioValue = $("input[name='yesno']:checked").val();**

**Second**: Assign the checked radio button value to the hidden input field.

```js
$(document).ready(function(e) {

  $("input[type='radio']").click(function(){
      var radioValue = $("input[name='yesno']:checked").val();      
      if(radioValue) {   
          $("#radioCheck").val(radioValue);
          console.clear();
          console.log($("#radioCheck").val());
      }
   });
    
})
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="image_radioButton">
<input id="image_radio_check" value="imageButtonChecked" type="radio" class="radio_button" name="yesno" /> Image Radio Button
</div>


<div class="text_radioButton">
<input id="text_radio_check" value="textButtonChecked" type="radio" class="radio_button" name="yesno" />Text Radio Button
</div>

<div class="hidden_input"> 
  <input type="hidden" name="radioCheck" id="radioCheck" value=""/>
</div>
```

Hope this may hep you in solving your problem.